# "NoSuchWindowException: no such window: window was already closed" while switching tabs using Selenium and WebDriver through Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a form that opens in a new tab when I click on it. When I try to navigate to that new tab, I keep getting a NoSuchWindowException. Code is pretty straightforward. 'myframe' is the frame within the new tab that the information will eventually get plugged into. Should I be waiting for something else?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time
import pandas as pd

url = *****
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'S:\Engineering\Jake\MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms\chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)    

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.find_element_by_id('portal.scheduling.prepopulate').click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
driver.switch_to_default_content()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('myframe'))
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-308-2aa72eeedd51>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('S:/Engineering/Jake/MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms/Pipette Completing CalPM Tasks.py', wdir='S:/Engineering/Jake/MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "S:/Engineering/Jake/MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms/Pipette Completing CalPM Tasks.py", line 150, in <module>
    create_new_cal_task(asset_number)

  File "S:/Engineering/Jake/MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms/Pipette Completing CalPM Tasks.py", line 130, in create_new_cal_task
    driver.switch_to_default_content()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 783, in switch_to_default_content
    self._switch_to.default_content()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py", line 65, in default_content
    self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': None})

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchWindowException: no such window: window was already closed
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using

```
While True:
    try:
        [navigate to the new frame, wait for a specific element to show up]
        break
    except (NoSuchWindowException, NoSuchElementException):
        pass
```

I had not realized that when I clicked to open the form, another window opened briefly in the background, then closed. This increased the window_handles to 2, so doing anything relating to waiting for 2 window handles still kept throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question and your code trials when you intend *to navigate to a new tab* you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* while *switching* to the *New Tab*.
- Again when you intend to `switch()` to the desired `<iframe>` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* again.
- While you `switch()` to the desired `<iframe>` try to use either *ID*, *NAME*, *XPATH* or *CSS-SELECTOR* of the desired `<iframe>`.
- Your own code with these simple modification will be as follows:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  url = "your_url"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'S:\Engineering\Jake\MasterControl Completing Pipette CalPM Forms\chromedriver')
  driver.get(url)
  windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
  driver.find_element_by_id('portal.scheduling.prepopulate').click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = driver.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
  # driver.switch_to_window(new_window) <!---deprecated>
  driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"myframe"))) # or By.NAME, By.XPATH, By.CSS_SELECTOR
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to update your chrome version. The same error occurred for me, which happened in chrome 70, after an update to 91, it is ok.