# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window error clicking an element within an iframe using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm starting with Selenium and have a question, basically I don't understand why when I switch to an iframe and select one of the elements I constantly get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

This is the relevan code, firstly I click on some element of the DOM containing the iframe that actually updates the iframe content and then select the iframe, switch to it and then select the element I want inside the HTML content of the iframe

```
# Select the item on main DOM that will udpate the iframe contents
bandeja = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sm20']")
bandeja.click()
# Tried sleeping, but also WedDriverWait to no avails...
time.sleep(3)
# Get the frame that actually has the content
frame = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="ifrInterior")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# Select the element inside the iframe and click
equipo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='gestionesPropias_Equipo']")
equipo.click()
```

Now if I debug this, I don't get the error above, and I can see there element has been selected...but upon click nothing happens

[image]

This is the expected element, even checked the screenshot in base64 and it looks ok, it's a radio input button...just wondering why click doesn't work??

UPDATE: Based on response from @DebanjanB I used his sugestion and this works but the button does not get clicked

Upon clicking there should a new drop down be enabled

This is the radio button:

[image]

When clicked this drop-down is enabled:

[image]

The relevant code about this element

```
<span id="filtroAsignado" class="W30">
            
    <select name="nuumaAsignado" class="W84">       
        <option value="">[Todo mi equipo]</option></select>
            
</span>
```

So now I wonder why this does not get clicked?

Comment: Are you getting the error in line `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='gestionesPropias_Equipo']")`?

Comment: @supputuri nope, actually is when I do the click equipo.click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  # Select the item on main DOM that will udpate the iframe contents
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sm20"))).click()
  # Don't sleep, but only WedDriverWait...
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[value='ifrInterior']")))
  # Select the element inside the iframe and click
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='gestionesPropias_Equipo']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  # Select the item on main DOM that will udpate the iframe contents
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sm20']"))).click()
  # Don't sleep, but only WedDriverWait...
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@value='ifrInterior']")))
  # Select the element inside the iframe and click
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='gestionesPropias_Equipo']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

---

### tl; dr

[“NoSuchWindowException: no such window: window was already closed” while switching tabs using Selenium and WebDriver through Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775122/nosuchwindowexception-no-such-window-window-was-already-closed-while-switchi/51788519#51788519)

Comment: Hello @DebanjaB while this works and now I don't get the exception, the button does not get clicked...I'm updating the first post with pictures on what should be expected, as you can see, upon clicking a new section is shown with a dropdown...that is not shown obviously because I can see the radio button not being clicked upon...any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: @AlejandroVK This answer was specifically to address the `NoSuchWindowException` error. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144037/element-not-being-clicked-even-though-it-is-found-using-selenium