# Python Selenium: Closing a new tab with driver.close() is probably causing "no such window: target window already closed; web view not found" error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles, selenium-webdriver-python

Recently I have started working with multiple tabs in Selenium and I have encountered a strange problem. When I'm executing this code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
time.sleep(1)
url_in_page_source= eu.look_for_url_in_page_source(
    page_html=driver.page_source,
    left_delimiter='placeholder',
    right_delimiter='placeholder'
)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
# time.sleep(10) # <--- this is fixing the error
return url_in_page_source
```

and immediately after the return statement when I'm trying to visit extracted url by `driver.get()` I'm getting this error:

```
Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

However I have found out that adding a simple `time.sleep(10)` just before `return` statement is fixing the issue, but what is more strange to me - when I have tried to lower the wait time just below 10 secs the error is still existing. I have no idea why it is happening. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I will be very grateful for any help and explanations.

Edit:
Here's source code of the `eu.look_for_url_in_page_source()` as per @JeffC request

```
def look_for_url_in_page_source(page_html, left_url_delimiter, right_url_delimiter):
    print('Processing URL with f:look_for_url_in_page_source()')
    # extracts multiple URLs from page_source
    extracted_urls = []
    while True:
        # check if delimiters are present in page_html
        find_left_url_delimiter = page_html.find(left_url_delimiter)
        find_right_url_delimiter = page_html.find(right_url_delimiter)
        if find_left_url_delimiter == -1 or find_right_url_delimiter == -1:
            if len(extracted_urls) > 0:
                return extracted_urls
            print('f:look_for_url_in_page_source() was not able to get any text.')
            return False
        left_url_delimiter_pos = find_left_url_delimiter + len(left_url_delimiter)
        right_url_delimiter_pos = page_html[left_url_delimiter_pos:].find(right_url_delimiter) + left_url_delimiter_pos
        extracted_url = page_html[left_url_delimiter_pos:right_url_delimiter_pos].strip()
        extracted_urls.append(extracted_url)
        page_html = page_html[right_url_delimiter_pos:]
```

Comment: What does `eu.look_for_url_in_page_source()` do? We can't see the code. What code is running right after this method returns? We need a [mcve].

Comment: @JeffC I didn't include `eu.look_for_url_in_page_source()` source code, because it doesn't do much to be honest. It is just using python's built-in string `find()` method to extract URL from page source. It is not causing the problem for sure, because error is happening after the return statement when other function is trying to get that extracted URL with Selenium's `driver.get()`.

Comment: The problem is happening when you do `driver.get()` using the URL that was returned from `eu.look_for_url_in_page_source()` so I think it's very relevant.

Comment: @JeffC I've updated my question with source code of the look_for_url_in_page_source().

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot many process involved in the process of closing a tab and switching to the parent *Browsing Context* which is beyond the scope of our naked eyes. Having said that, ***neither***

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

is an ideal way to switch to the new tab, ***nor***

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

is an ideal way to switch to the parent tab.

> You can find a detailed discussion on tab switching in [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893230/7429447)

---

### References

A few relevant discussions:

- ["NoSuchWindowException: no such window: window was already closed" while switching tabs using Selenium and WebDriver through Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788519/7429447)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I've tried the solution which you've provided in another question, but it didn't change anything. Before implementing switching windows with your way I've already tried printing windows and it was switching to and closing correct ones, so closing wrong window it's probably not the issue here. Do you have any other ideas?